# Establish a Live Video Stream Using a WebCam

Tags: c#, video-streaming, webcam, live

There are a "WebCam Station" which is a PC running window, a "Host(Windows Server)" and people!
How can i provide a Live video Strem from "WebCam Station" to "Host" and manage it so people can watch it in their PCs browser? and i have NOT a static IP!
i don't need fully control on the video. The goal is playing the stream in a box in the web page(like youtube).
thank you for taking time.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the many existing service such as Google+ Hangouts, Skype, Ustream, Justin.tv, ...?

Comment: they all need some Google or Skype account or a app to be installed. I don't want to bother visitors of website. I want them to start watching the video right after enter the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There are services like ***UStream*** (http://www.ustream.tv/), cross platform, that allow you to perform such task directly from your webcam (Flash based/enabled) and they also offer propietary software and/or web tools that you can customize based in your needs in order to increase the streamer's experience when running a broadcast.

For the final user's side, you will be able to gather a plain html code that you can provide both in a server or just by delivering the proper html file, let's call it "stream.html". This wy you can use it as a template for an email in order to watch your contents directly from the inbox of the people that receives the email and or as an attachment which can be downloaded and run from their favorite web browser (updated of course).

If the users open the email/file and you haven't started the broadcast they will receive an "offline" message which can be customized in order to provide your logo or anything else. If they keep the page open and you suddenly start the broadcast, it will be shown instantly in the final user's side.

The same behavior is observed by ***Qik*** (*[Powered by Skype](http://blogs.skype.com/en/2011/01/qik.html)* http://qik.com/) which is an application for modern mobile devices such as iPhone/iPad and Android based cellphones/tablets.

In both cases, uni-directional communication is allowed but with some programming skills (html/css) you can build a bi-directional communication system. I am sure that with some efforts it can also be made multi-directional but there are some services (google+ in example) that already provides such functionality.

If you need further help, don't hesitate to drop a comment and if you open a related question please drop back a link in order to continue the support with you.

Good luck!

Comment: first of all thank you. as i said before i can't use any services that requires any account. I'm test some way through VLC. look likes it's working. i'll tell you about result.